# Is there any better way to get the value from an array?

Tags: java

I have assigned the value

```
Menu[] food = {new Menu ("A01", "Burger", 10.00), ...}
Menu[] drinks = {...}
```

in main function

When i want to get the value of price as user input the **ID** at another function from both arrays, i am using **two *for loop*** to get the price

```
for (int i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    do{
        if(food[i].getMenuID().equals(id)){
            //codes
        }
    }while(!food[i].getMenuID().equals(id));
}
for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++){
    do{
        if(drinks[i].getMenuID().equals(id)){
            //codes
        }
    }while(!drinks[i].getMenuID().equals(id));
}
```

can i know is there any better way to get the price value?

Comment: Try a hash map?

Comment: Or a hash set even, presuming that you don't have two menu items with the same ID. Of course then you need to override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Java 1.8+ has streams. You can apply filter and map with that to do things in a simpler fashion. Also you can merge streams. (or your arrays if drink contained same Menus structure. Unclear from the question)

Comment: Just a small note on your class design: I don't think `Menu` is a good name for a single burger. `MenuItem` is probably better, as in "an item on the menu". And your arrays should probably not be split by food and drinks, I mean, what to do with Cafe Gourmet (other than to order and eat / drink it, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is absolutly useless, just do it with one

```
String id = "A01";
Menu toFind = null;

for (int i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    if(food[i].getMenuID().equals(id)){
        toFind = food[i];
        System.out.println("Got it !");
        break;
    }
}
```

The correspondant solution using `Streams` (java>8) is the following

```
Menu myMenu = Arrays.asList(food).stream().filter(menu -> menu.id.equals(id))
                                          .findAny().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (**if you use java 1.8+**):

```
String id = "A01"

Menu myMenu = Arrays.asList(food)
.stream()
.filter(menu -> menu.id.equals(id))
.findAny()
.orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to get prices by the menu item's key, it's better to use a hash map in that case (Map.of(...) is from Java 9) :

```
Map<String, Menu> drinks = Map.of("A01", new Menu ("Cola", 10.00),
                          "A02", new Menu ("Fanta", 11.00));
Manu menu = drinks.get("A01")
```

Or you can use streams API (Java 8+) if you don't like the approach with maps:

```
Menu[] food = {new Menu ("A01", "Burger", 10.00), ...}
String menuIdToSearchFor = "A01";
Optional<Menu> optionalMenu = Arrays.stream(food)
       .filter(menu -> menuIdToSearchFor.equals(menu.getMenuId())
       .findFirst()
       .orElse(...);
```

Comment: Streams appeared in Java 1.8. Per my comment before you posted!

Comment: @JGFMK you're right. I've put the Java 9+ caption for the "Map.of()" method. I have corrected the answer to express that the second approach works with Java 1.8 too. Thanks.